# How to get the ddl of at table in oracle other then get_ddl procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get the ddl of a table which is present in other database. 
is it possible to get the ddl of table using DB link.

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of a tricky job. I've never had to do it, but - Phil knows *how*. He shared his code (as he said, tested on 9i and 10g); see if it helps.

Link to his blog: [DBMS_METADATA Across Database Links!](http://phil-sqltips.blogspot.com/2009/06/dbmsmetadata-across-database-links.html).

---

(Yes, I know; some people say that it is better to post code than links, but no - I'm not going to do that because a) code is quite long, b) I don't have Phil's permission to do that. Therefore, link is all you get).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible - or at least not easily. You could make educated guesses based on data in all_tables, or all_tab_cols, but getting storage-level info and other parameters (constraints, indexes, etc.) and reverse-engineering workable DDL commands would be more difficult. get_ddl would be the only way that I know of to be *sure*. I must also say that I do not find this surprising: being able to generate DDL for remote objects over a database link would be considered a HUGE security vulnerability for most systems.